# How to download a apple developer profile to use in xcuitrunner?

Tags: ios, windows

I am new to iOS. So i have some doubt related to the xcuitrunner parameters like:

-d [path to your developer profile]

From where i can get this and how this actually looks like. I have a apple developer account but when i am downloading a developer certificate and trying to use it .It is throwing an error as not a valid development profile.

-k [path to the directory containing the developer disk images]

From where and how can i get the developer disk images

-l [path your Quamotion license file]

From where i will get the quamotion licence

If anyone can help me then it will be great

Answer (score 0):

#### Developer Profile

There's a difference between an Apple Developer Profile and an Apple Developer Certificate. The certificate is a `.cer`, `.pfx` or `.p12` file, whereas a developer profile is a `.developerprofile` file.

To export your developer profile from Xcode:

1. On your Mac machine, open *Xcode* and click *Xcode*, *Preferences...*
2. In the *Preferences* window, choose *Accounts*
3. At the bottom of the *Accounts* window, click the gear icon, and choose *Export Accounts*
4. In the *Save* dialog, choose a file name and enter a password to protect the file. You will need this password later.
5. If a warning appears about Xcode exporting the private key, click *Allow*

#### Developer Disk Images

The Developer Disk Images are located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

#### Trial License

You can request a trial license for Quamotion at http://quamotion.mobi/Mwc/license. You'll need your Machine ID, which appears when your run `xcuitrunner`.